Can I use a double pole 60 amp breaker on a 40 amp tankless hot water heater
How can I properly wire a double pole 60 amp breaker at the breaker box to be use on a 40 amp tankless hot water heater

is this a new installation? Do you have the written operator manual and installation instructions? Is this unit supposed to be powered by a single 2-pole breaker or multiple  2-pole breakers?

40 amps is usually tiny for tankless, unless for single source.  for 40 amps you should use a 40amp breaker.  If you have 60 amp wire already, they can be use on the smaller breaker.

What does the installation manual specify for maximum breaker size?  The bottom line is that the breaker needs to be sized appropriately for the load, as well as the size of the wires.  If the unit instructions say to use 40A breakers, then you need to swap them out to 40A breakers.  If the wiring is only good for 40A based on wire size, then you need to downgrade the breakers to 40A to provide sufficient protection for the wiring.  Also, make sure the heater has a UL listing.  If not, it's not tested to be safe, and needs to be replaced with a unit with proper safety testing and approvals.

First thing to do is make sure it only takes a single 40A circuit. There are plenty of tankless water heaters that take 2 or even 3 40A circuits. If it requires 2 or more 40A circuits then you need the appropriate number of 40A or larger circuits.
Let's assume for a moment that this water heater only needs a single 40A circuit. If that's the case, you must (a) use a breaker that is at least 40A, (b) use wire that is rated at least large enough for the size of the breaker, and (c) follow all manufacturer directions.
For breaker size, you are OK. 60A > 40A. Done.
For wire size, it can get complicated. The minimum wire size for a 40A circuit is 8 AWG. For 60A, it varies depending on the wire type. See an ampacity chart for details, but 60A typically requires 4 AWG copper cable or 6 AWG copper wires in conduit or 4 AWG aluminum wires in conduit. It is worth checking to see what you have, because it is not unheard of for a 40A circuit to be increased to a 60A breaker without replacing the wire with the required larger size. If the wires are too small for 60A but are at least 8 AWG then the solution is to replace the 60A breaker with a 40A breaker.
Finally, the manufacturer's instructions may or may not give any specific details. They may say "40A breaker" or "40A circuit" and that can be interpreted as only 40A. They may say "at least a 40A breaker" or "at least a 40A circuit" or "40A or larger" or similar, in which case 60A is fine. You can always play it safe by replacing the 60A breaker with a 40A breaker. Standard double breakers are not very expensive, typically $15 - $40, depending on where you buy them and what type of panel.

Why are you implying that aluminum cable isn't an option? It does exist and is absolutely normal to use for high-amperage loads.

@nobody I didn't mean to imply that, so much as I wanted to make clear that there are size differences depending on cable vs. wire and copper vs. aluminum.
